# Build configuration for Lite/Full apps in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm developing a Lite version of an existing iPhone app and I'm trying to figure out the best way to conditionally compile the full and lite versions. Ideally I'd like to use a LITE preprocessor define but is there a good way to set this so I can choose a different item from the scheme menu and just compile whichever version I want?

I don't want to duplicate my "full" target because I'm concerned I'll change a setting in one version and not copy it to the other one. I looked at using an aggregate target but it doesn't run when I press Command-R.

What's the best way to achieve this without duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided it was best to resolve this without using build configurations. My app uses in-app-purchase to support upgrading to the full, non-lite, version. As such, I want to have every feature compiled and ready to go.

I now manually update the bundle identifier if I want to switch between full and lite versions, and check this when the app runs. I have to change the bundle identifier anyway when I submit either version, so this way I change one file and there's no duplication. Within the app I call the method below to enable/disable lite features.

```
+ (BOOL)isLiteVersion {
    static BOOL haveCheckedLiteStatus = NO;    
    if (haveCheckedLiteStatus == NO) {
        BOOL isLiteApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] rangeOfString:@"lite"].location != NSNotFound;
        isLite = isLiteApp && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kUpgraded] == NO;

        haveCheckedLiteStatus = YES;
    }

    return isLite;
}
```

Comment: That code looks weird. `isLite` variable is in a different scope on initialize and return line. There should be an error.

Comment: Actually isLite is declared outside this method (as a static). It's hard to distinguish it from isLiteApp though - a better name for either variable would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your using xcode4? You could do this by defining a new configuration (beyond the standard ones of Debug & Release).

Then, add your own preprocessor macro for the additional configuration.

Finally, add a new scheme to select the new configuration.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but I'll have to create Debug, Release and Distribution configurations for Lite as well as those that already exist for the Full version. It might be the best solution, but I'd love to find an approach that avoided the duplication.